# Wordpress if I edit my page then I redirect to another page

Tags: wordpress

I want to edit my start page, if I press on edit Site, then I redirect to a site that is not the same as my start page ? What could the problem ?

Pic 1
[image]

if I press on "Seite bearbeiten" (Edit post) then I get redirect to this site below:

Pic 2
[image]

This is not the same site, what I have to do ?

Answer (score 0):

May be it is something like tutorial by wordpress just go to dashboard and delete this page and then check is it again visible or not.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).